# Return the search result after HTTPPOST in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have search form to search by : site, user, status and date. After searched I will do Reject, Re-submit or Approve to call the controller action for update the status in the database. My code are as below:

/// View :

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
```

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())   // Begin Form
```

{

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Site:</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("sites", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.sites, "-- ALL --", new { style = "width: 300px;" })</td>
         <td>Status:</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("status", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.status, "-- ALL --", new { style = "width: 150px;" })</td>
        <td>PO No:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("PONumber", null, new { style = "width:150px" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>User: </td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("user", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.user, "-- ALL --", new { style = "width: 300px;" })</td>
        <td>Department:</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("department", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.department, "-- ALL --", new { style = "width: 150px;" })
        </td>

        <td>Transaction Date:
        </td>
        <td>
            @*<input type="text" id="TransactionDate" name="TransactionDate" style="width:210px"  />*@
            @*@Html.TextBox("TransactionDate", null, new { @class="datefield", style = "width:150px", @Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })*@
            @Html.TextBox("TransactionDate", null, new { @class="datefield", style = "width:150px" })
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Search" />

// Here is the search result table

<input type="submit" value="Re-Submit" name="action" />
<input type="submit" value="Approve" name="action" />
<input type="submit" value="Reject" name="action" />
```

}  // End Form

//// Controller

```
// HTTP Get
public ActionResult POHeader(string sites, string user, string department,
        string status, string PONumber, string TransactionDate, bool IsRedirectAction = false)
    {


        // Populate Dropdown List 
        GetSiteDropdownList(SiteId);
        GetUserDropdownList(UserId);
        GetDepartmentDropdownList(DepartmentId);
        GetStatusDropdownList(StatusId);


            var PO = from p in db.X_PO_HDR
                 select p;

            // Get Selected Site
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sites)) || ((TempData["selectedsite"] != null)))
            {
                if (sites.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (IsRedirectAction)
                    {
                        SiteId = (string)TempData["selectedsite"];
                        //sites = SiteId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SiteId = sites;
                        TempData["selectedsite"] = SiteId;
                    }

                    // Get Selected Site
                    PO = PO.Where(p => p.Site_Id == SiteId);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || ((TempData["selectedUser"] != null)))
            {
                if (user.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (IsRedirectAction)
                    {
                        UserId = (string)TempData["selectedUser"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UserId = user;
                        TempData["selectedUser"] = UserId;
                    }

                    // Filter by User
                    PO = PO.Where(p => p.Created_By == UserId);
                }
            }

            // Get Selected Department            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(department) || ((TempData["selectedDepartment"] != null)))
            {
                if (department.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (IsRedirectAction)
                    {
                        DepartmentId = (string)TempData["selectedDepartment"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DepartmentId = department;
                        TempData["selectedDepartment"] = DepartmentId;
                    }

                    // Filter by Department
                    PO = PO.Where(p => p.Purch_Dept == DepartmentId);
                }
            }

            PO = PO.OrderBy(o => o.Txn_DT);

            // check if TempData contains some error message and if yes add to the model state.
            if (TempData["CustomError"] != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, TempData["CustomError"].ToString());
            }

            return View(PO.ToList());

    }
```

/// HttpPost Action

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("POHeader")]
    [MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "Reject")]
    public ActionResult Reject(int[] selectedList)
    {
        string var1 = collection["sites"];
        UpdateListStatus(selectedList, "X", "Rejected");
        TempData["CustomError"] = selectedList.Count().ToString() + " record(s) has been successfully " + ActionString + "!";
       return RedirectToAction("POHeader", new { IsRedirectAction = true });

    }
```

Question: How to get back the search values?
1. Do I need to pass all the parameters again at HTTPPost Action? (any better way to solve?)
2. CustomError message is not working. (Message appear after next search is done)

Thanks,
Si Thu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start out by binding the View to a model. By doing this you can pass the entire model back to your method, then if there are issues with the form and you need to show it again with the values, you just return back the view along with the model you sent.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult POHeader(FormModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Do whatever you want to do and redirect to wherever you want to go from here.
   }

   // If the Model is invalid then simply return back the view along with the invalid model.
   return View(model)
}
```

See the following article for more information on Model Binding
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159749/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-Part1

Here is another article on Client Side Model validation
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation